# Does it make sense to seek tax deduction for a lecturer with 15K a year

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, travel, eligible-expenses

I am a lecturer with salary 15K per year. Does it make sense to seek deductions in my current situation?

Answer (score 1):

In 2018, the federal standard deduction for single filers is $12,000. It seems likely that your itemized deductions would not exceed this and so you do not need to be concerned with itemizing.

However, you may be eligible for [above-the-line deductions](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/deductions-you-can-take-without-itemizing.html) such as student loan interest.